# Neo4j Cypher query - relationship with an "or"

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I'm trying to get a named relationship with an `or` in the query. I'm thinking the query should look similar to:

`MATCH (A:person)-[B (:ACTED_IN|:DIRECTED)]->(C:person) RETURN A, B, C`

but no matter how I put in the parens I get an error. I suppose a `UNION` would do the trick but was hoping that there was some way of doing it similar to the above. TIA.

EDIT: This does what I want but seems *not* the way to do it.

`MATCH (A:person)-[B]->(C:person) WHERE type(B)="ACTED_IN" OR type(B)="DIRECTED" RETURN A,B,C`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a new user so I do not have the option to comment on questions yet. I am guessing you are trying to get the person who either acted in or directed the movie. Its described in official Cypher Documentation: [Match on multiple relationship types](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#match-on-multiple-rel-types).

With Demo Movie Data on Neo4j to get persons from The Matrix movie, I would use this:

```
MATCH (TheMatrix { title: 'The Matrix' })<-[rel:ACTED_IN|:DIRECTED]-(person)         
RETURN person.name, rel
```

Comment: That's close to what I want but you left the key part out - a name for the relationship.
I want `

MATCH ... [B (x or y)] ... RETURN ... B ...

`

Comment: If Mrinal would add a variable name, this should be an accepted answer. ```MATCH (TheMatrix { title: 'The Matrix' })<-[rel:ACTED_IN|:DIRECTED]-(person)
RETURN person.name, rel```